# How can I make my local plan path in navigation stack longer?

Tags: ros, navigation, path, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hy,

I have a pretty large robot which I'm trying to navigate using ROS Navigation stack. It is about 1.2m long and 0.8m wide. The problem is, when moving, the robot trajectory is oscillating around calculated global path (in other words - robot is not moving straight).
At first I thought that the problem could be in control loop frequency which couldn't reach higher than 4Hz but after solving that problem the robot was still acting basically the same.
Here is the link to the question about control loop frequency

http://answers.ros.org/question/227137/controller-frequency-in-navigation-stack/

When looking in rviz the calculated local plan, I find it very short (practically less than 30cm), when comparing it with my robots dimensions. It is always a lot shorter than my robot's footprint. So I was thinking if I could make my local plan longer the robot wouldn't oscillate that much.

So the question is - How can I make my local plan path in navigation stack longer?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227452/how-can-i-make-my-local-plan-path-in-navigation-stack-longer?/) by [Double X](https://answers.ros.org/users/25358/double-x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2016-02-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jiecuiok](https://answers.ros.org/users/27369/jiecuiok/) on 2016-07-03**:
hello, i meet the same problom, do you have solved this one?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-03**:
Hi @jiecuiok, could you please not post *answers* when you're not answering the question? Please use comments for these kinds of interactions. Thanks.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-07-04**:
what is the local planner you are using?

**Comment by [jiecuiok](https://answers.ros.org/users/27369/jiecuiok/) on 2016-07-04**:
the default local planner.I have solved this problem with tunning the sim_time and pdis_scale and gdis_scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using the default local planner of ROS, you can check the Forward Simulation Parameters (section 4.2.3) [here](http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner).

Try to play with those parameters, specially the `sim_time`, which is only 1.0 s by default. But beware that these parameters will have a visible impact on your cpu resources.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2016-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Double X](https://answers.ros.org/users/25358/double-x/) on 2016-07-04**:
Yes, I changed it with sim_time, although I have written my own node for local and global planing so I'm not using Navigation Stack any more. Thnx

**Comment by [kiran](https://answers.ros.org/users/24920/kiran/) on 2016-09-25**:
Hey, how is the performance using your own global and local planners? Even I am facing that problem. Depending on your answer I will try to solve this problem